# Libgdx Particle Editor: Blank UI elements

Tags: libgdx, particles

How can I get Libgdx Particle Editor to run properly on my 32-bit Windows 7 machine? When I run it, the UI elements are blank like this:

[image: Particle Editor screenshot]

Comment: You sure you got the latest/stable version? Also update your Java.

Comment: Hi Anik, could you please provide a few more details about your environment?

Comment: I have latest java version and also downloading the particle editor from 
http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/jws/particle-editor.jnlp

The problem is it is not launching in 64 bit windows 7 and in 32 bit it looks like the image, no UI element to work with. How to solve this?